# Can any one of the following compound propositions can be created by using only ‘$\to$’ and ‘$\vee$’?

Tags: logic

> Can any one of the following compound propositions can be created by using only ‘$\to$’ and ‘$\vee$’?
>
> (i)  $ ¬ P $
> (ii) $ P \wedge Q$
> (iii) $ P \leftrightarrow Q$

### My answer to (i)

Since  $¬$ is not a logical connective, it can not join two statements together.

Thus $¬$ can not be created by using $\to$ and $\wedge$.

Am I right? Also how to say true or false for the other two options?

Any help?

Comment: Note that if you can show (ii), then you can get (iii) by writing two implications.

Comment: $\lnot P \leftrightarrow (P \to \bot)$ So if $\bot$ (falsum) is allowed as a constant you're good to go.

Comment: $\neg$ is a logical connective. Being a logical connective, despite the name, doesn't have to do with "joining two statements together". The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective) hilariously starts out defining it that way, but then immediately contradicts itself in the next paragraph and the remainder of the article. Indeed, not only going on to say $\neg$ is "unary connective", but (correctly in my opinion) also suggesting that $\top$ and $\bot$ are best thought of as (nullary) connectives.

Comment: Agree with @DerekElkins The $\top$ can be treated as a nullary AND, and the $\bot$ as a nullary OR.  Also, you can create a unary connective from a binary connectice. For example, P NAND P = NOT P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can show by induction on the complexity of the formula $\phi \equiv \phi_1 \vee \phi_2$ or $\psi \equiv \psi_1 \rightarrow \psi_2$ that the formula does not imply $\neg P$.

$\bf Base\ case.$ No atomic formula $Q$ implies $\neg P$.

$\bf Induction\ step\ 1.$ If either $\phi_1$ or $\phi_2$ fails to imply another formula $\theta$ (such as $\neg P$) then $\phi_1 \vee \phi_2$ also fails to imply $\theta$. (This may be easier to see from the counterfactual: if $\phi_1 \vee \phi_2$ implies $\theta$, then both $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ do as well.)

$\bf Induction\ step\ 2.$ If $\psi_2$ fails to imply $\theta$ then $\psi_1 \rightarrow \psi_2$ fails to imply $\theta$. (If you like, this can be because $\psi_1 \rightarrow \psi_2$ is equivalent to $\neg \psi_1 \vee \psi_2 $, which lets us reduce the $\rightarrow$ case to the $\vee$ case.)

---

Question for you: does this strategy also work for (ii) $P \wedge Q$ and (iii) $P \leftrightarrow Q$? Or can you solve these cases by some other means, e.g. the sort of argument  John Griffin has used in the comments to show (ii) implies (iii)?

---

Your reasoning that binary connectives be can't say anything about unary formulas is not correct in general. A famous and popular example of this behaviour is that $(P \rightarrow Q) \rightarrow P$ actually implies $P$.

Comment: To expand on your final point, we also have that $\neg P \equiv P\barwedge P$, where $\barwedge$ denotes the nand binary connective.